# Understanding Raku's approach to Exception type hierarchy (or lack thereof)

Tags: exception, types, hierarchy, raku, rakudo

Raku provides a number of exception types that, on a conceptual level, are subtypes of each other.  For example, `X::Bind::Slice` is conceptually a sub-category of `X::Bind`.  But at an object-hierarchy level, `X::Bind::Slice` is **not** a subtype of `X::Bind` in Rakudo – it inherits directly from `Exception`.  And for many exceptions, the thing-that-looks-like-a-supertype isn't even an `Exception`; e.g., `X::Method` is a `Package`.

On the other hand, `X::IO` is a `Role` which is done by various `X::IO::*` exceptions; thus `X::IO::Copy ~~ X::IO` returns `True` (unlike, say, `X::Bind::Slice ~~ X::Bind`).

Is there a particular reason for the various typing relationships implemented in Rakudo? (I say "Rakudo" because I'm not aware of any specs covering these relationships).

More practically, what sort of type hierarchy is advisable for my own exception types?  My current practice has been to have a base `MyModule::X` type, with subtypes for different categories of errors, which in turn have subtypes for specific errors.  (This approach allows for smartmatching against error categories, which can be handy).  But that's pretty different than any of the approaches I see in Rakudo.

Am I missing a good reason to have a flat `X::*` hierarchy?  Or, alternately, to have the "exception categories" be roles rather than types in the way `X::IO` is?

Comment: You can have any organization you want; there?s no convention and even if there were, no linter to enforce it. MyModule::X seems reasonable enough, as well as X::MyModule which would make all exceptions occupy the X:: namespace. At the end of the day, using roles or a flat namespace is very problem-dependent, I would say. Domain driven design could help with a sound methodology, but that's not Raku-speak, it's simply best practice.

Comment: Ignoring Rakudo, off the top of my head, aiui, in Raku, it's something like: **Names are just names**, `::` is a way to organize names into spaces with a notional hierarchy; **Packages are just packages** (some digital stuff that isn't objects) that are often associated with names or name spaces; and finally, **Types are just types** (though they are often associated with names, and/or packages which in turn are often associated with names), and to the degree there are hierarchies of types, those type hierarchies are technically about inheritance, not technically about names or packages.

Comment: fwiw I thought this was quite relevant https://docs.raku.org/type/Exception#typegraphrelations

Comment: @librasteve Yeah, that's sweet! My "off the top of my head" comment said "to the degree there are hierarchies of types, those hierarchies are technically about inheritance", but (duh) they can also be about: `does` chains with *compositional* semantics but nominal hierarchy (discoverable via `type.^roles`); parameterized types such as `Array[Int]` (whose hierarchies are discoverable by a hack deconstructing a type's name); mixins such as `say B.new but 42; # B+{<anon|1>}.new` (discoverable by an even worse hack); and delegation chains (I don't even know where I'd start to deconstruct those!).

Comment: Re: the two "hack"s of my previous message: To deconstruct a single level parameterized type, just call `.of`, eg. `say Array[Int].of; # (Int)`, and repeat for more depth.  For mixins start with a `.^roles`, eg `(B.new but 42).^roles`.